# CSS3 animation was, but is no longer working in webkit broswers

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-animations

I have two divs that I want to fade in and slide toward each other, so I have 3 animations: fadeIn, slideRight, and slideLeft. These animations were all working in Firefox AND webkit browsers, but suddenly slideRight stopped working in webkit browsers. That element still fades in and the other element still fades in and slides left.

I've looked at it for hours (including looking at countless other stackoverflow answers) and am extremely confused because of the other working parts. Let me know if you can think of what could be wrong!

css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideRight{
  from{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px)}
  to{-webkit-transform:translateX(0)}
}
@-moz-keyframes slideRight{
  from{-moz-transform:translateX(-20px)}
  to{-moz-transform:translateX(0)}
}
@-o-keyframes slideRight{
  from{-o-transform:translateX(-20px)}
  to{-o-transform:translateX(0)}
}
@keyframes slideRight{
  from{transform:translateX(-20px)}
  to{transform:translateX(0)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft{
  from{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px)}
  to{-webkit-transform:translateX(0)}
}
@-moz-keyframes slideLeft{
  from{-moz-transform:translateX(20px)}
  to{-moz-transform:translateX(0)}
}
@-o-keyframes slideLeft{
  from{-o-transform:translateX(20px)}
  to{-o-transform:translateX(0)}
}
@keyframes slideLeft{
  from{transform:translateX(20px)}
  to{transform:translateX(0)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn{
  from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn{
  from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}
}
@-o-keyframes fadeIn{
  from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}
}
@keyframes fadeIn{
  from{opacity:0}to{opacity:1}
}
#left{
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: slideRight 1500ms ease 1200ms, fadeIn 1500ms ease 1400ms;
  -moz-animation: slideRight 1500ms ease 1200ms, fadeIn 1500ms ease 1400ms;
  -o-animzation: slideRight 1500ms ease 1200ms, fadeIn 1500ms ease 1400ms;
  animation: slideRight 1500ms ease 1200ms, fadeIn 1500ms ease 1400ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;  
}
#right{
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-animation: slideLeft 1500ms ease 1200ms, fadeIn 1500ms ease 1400ms;
  -moz-animation: slideLeft 1500ms ease 1200ms, fadeIn 1500ms ease 1400ms;
  -o-animzation: slideLeft 1500ms ease 1200ms, fadeIn 1500ms ease 1400ms;
  animation: slideLeft 1500ms ease 1200ms, fadeIn 1500ms ease 1400ms;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

html is simply:

```
<div id="left">
  /* some content */
</div>
<div id="right">
  /* some content */
<div>
```

The website is http://gavel.co so you can see what is happening. Please let me know if any other information would be helpful! Thanks so much.

Comment: This is interesting. Your snippet works fine, just not on your site. **Sidenote:** [You only really need the webkit prefix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) -  [like this example](http://jsbin.com/vumene/1/edit)

Comment: @misterManSam Thank you for the advice! I'll clean up the other prefixes. Could it be that some js or other code is interfering with the above code, since it works fine alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I had a "comment" right above this particular CSS that was not a proper CSS comment.

I had

```
< !--animation css-->
```

instead of

```
/* animation css */
```

so the first line of code after the incorrect comment (i.e., the webkit browser slide right animation) was not interpreted correctly.